# Determine the values of $t$ that make the two vectors orthogonal

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

In a book of mine I stumbled upon this question and was wondering whether I have solved it properly.

The task is to determine all values of $t$ that makes the two vectors orthogonal

$u⃗=\binom{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}$   and  $x⃗=\binom{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)-2\sin(t)}$ where $t\in [0;2\pi]$

Here is my solution:
We know that
$u⃗\perp x⃗ \iff u⃗\cdot x⃗=0$

From that we have

$0=\cos(t)\cdot \sin(t)+\sin(t)\cdot (\cos(t)-2\sin(t))$

$0=2\cdot \sin(t)\cdot (\cos(t)-\sin(t))$

$0=\sin(t)\cdot (\cos(t)-\sin(t))$

That means we have:

$0=\sin(t)$ and $0=\cos(t)-\sin(t)$

Let's look at the first equation

$0=\sin(t)$ to this we can make a general solution: $\sin(n\pi)=0$ where $n\in [0;2\pi]$

From this we have 3 solutions;

$n=0,n=1,n=2$

This means that

$\sin(0)=0$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$ and $\sin(2\pi)=0$

For this reason our first 3 solutions are

$t=0,t=1,t=2$

Now we look at

$0=\cos(t)-\sin(t)$

$0={\cos(t)-\sin(t)\over \cos(t)}$

$0=1-\tan(t)$

$\tan(t)=1$

We know that

$\tan(45)=1$ because $\tan^{-1}(1)={\pi \over 4}$ this means that $\tan({\pi \over 4})=1$

Now we can say that if $\tan(t)=1$ has $t={\pi \over 4}$ as a solution then $n\pi+{\pi \over 4}$ is the general solution.

If we let $n=1$ we have $\pi+{\pi \over 4}={5\pi \over 4}$

To sum up all the solutions to this problem are:

$t=0,t=\pi ,t=2\pi ,t={\pi \over 4}$ and $t={5\pi \over 4}$

Basically, my questions are: have i solved this properly? and do any of you guys have a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: Seems pretty neat to me.

Comment: You solved it correctly, with some shortcomings. 1. $n\color{red}{\pi}\in[0,2\pi]$. 2. $t=0,t=1,t=2$ is wrong as intermediate result. 3. it is in general better to use $\cos t-\sin t =\sqrt2 \cos(t+\pi/4)$ instead of divding by $\cos t$.

Comment: Ah so the intermediate results should be $t=0,t=\pi$ and $t=2\pi$?